# Update of view in private qgis.db failed. disk I/O error

Tags: qgis

I have compiled the QGIS Source code on windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019. I am getting this error while launching the application:

> Update of view in private qgis.db failed.disk I/O error.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: which version of QGIS? Also how are you launching the application?

Comment: Hi @nr_aus, I am using 3.29.0 version of QGIS. I am launching the application from Visual studio 2019 IDE or from the output folder where the executable has created from compiling the QGIS Code.

Comment: can you replicate the issue with a different/earlier version? I believe 3.22 is still the LTR.